When Debian auto-mounts my phone, is it possible to access it via the command line?
I think I would perhaps have my problem solved if this answer was still current. ...It's got to be a udev problem - or solution anyway!
In short, I need to run rsync to synchronize - a GUI interface isn't going to do it and I couldn't figure out where the phone was mounted!
Note that the GUI gives me a URL, not a file-system-path.
However, I CAN do this, just with extra effort, including requiring root access, if I use jmtpfs and give it a location... AND to do that I also have to first unmount the phone which I, so far, only know how to do via the GUI - horribly inconvenient...
